# Too few parameters. Expected <number>. (Error 3061)

Tags: vba

I'm getting error 3601 on this code when i run it,it says there are too few parameters, any solutions?

```
Sub copySDback()
Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Dim test As String

Dim sdSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
moo = "SD12401064"

sdSQL = "SELECT [Test EUS BL].[Ticket Nbr], [Test EUS BL].[Current Assignment Group],              [Test EUS BL].[ELEVATION STATUS] FROM [Test EUS BL] WHERE ((([Test EUS BL].[Ticket     Nbr])=SD16818515));"
'CurrentDb.OpenRecordset sdSQL

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sdSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
    rs.Close
    MsgBox "name not found"
End If
Exit Sub

rs.Close
db.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

In this segment of your query

```
WHERE ((([Test EUS BL].[Ticket     Nbr])=SD16818515))
```

It looks like you have more than one space between **Ticket** and **Nbr** (this may be a formatting issue) but this must be exact when using the square brackets.  Also, not related to the parameter required problem, you need to surround `SD16818515` with single quotes like

```
'SD16818616'
```

because it is a string.